# How to restore an unavailable WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-lightsail

I removed a harmful plugin from our Lightsail WordPress site, now the site is unavailable. I can not login. I can connect via SFTP.

Is it a way to restore site by copy out files?

[image]

Comment: You can download all the files from `wp-content`. The other important data is stored in the database - do a full export or mysqldump. And set up a new wordpress. Maybe the mentioned plugin isn't completely deactivated or deleted - try to rename the folder of the plugin in `wp_content/plugins` first.

Comment: Do you know, why do I not see any images in `wp-content`? No `wp-content/uploads` I can found. I am using LightSail.

Comment: Sorry, no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week, and it was not because of the removed plugin.
Are you sure that it's not a problem with too big database file ?
I had to many revisions. Once it was solved, It whas possible to connect with wp.login.php